# How to disconnect a network drive using powershell

Tags: networking, connection, powershell

I would like to disconnect a network drive (Y:) with powershell. That drive letter is assigned / mapped to a network location. Is there a simple way to do that?

I believe "net use XXX /delete" would do that.

The problem is:

```
C:\Windows>net use
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           Y:        \\192.168.1.108\d         Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

why when I try:

```
C:\Windows>net use \\192.168.1.108\d  /del
```

I get:

```
C:\Windows>net use \\192.168.1.108\d  /del
The network connection could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.
```

????

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In powershell you could issue a set of commands like this to disconnect a drive, given only the UNC that you used to connect, and not knowing the drive letter that was mapped.

The tricky part is that you have to escape the `\` character to use it in the WMI query.

```
$Drive = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_mappedLogicalDisk -filter "ProviderName='\\\\192.168.1.108\\d'"
net use $Drive.Name /delete
```

Comment: Add `/y` to `net use $Drive.Name /delete` to force close any open connections on the drive. If there are open connections, `net use` will prompt for action which you don't want in the middle of an unattended script run.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to suggest using PowerShell's own Remove-PSDrive.  For example:

```
Remove-PSDrive Y
```

Do not include a colon or a backslash; just use the drive letter only.

Comment: Remove-psdrive Y will not completely remove the drive and will leave a network drive mapping which will throw an error when you try to re-create the the ps-drive in the same session. You have to use net use /delete in order to negate this issue. it would be nice if the powershell remove-psdrive command actually removed the drive.

Comment: This is correct. PowerShell 5 supplies Remove-SmbMapping which does work (see answer below)

Answer (score 5):

Changed my answer based on your comment

> Net use Y: /delete

Comment: I believe i've not expressed myself good. What I want is to remove the drive from windows explorer.

Comment: and if I want to use the network address to do it?

Comment: you cant, you are disconnecting a drive, not a share

Comment: check initial post please

Comment: reword your initial post cause what Keltari said is right.  What he said will remove the drive from windows explorer

Comment: as you can see, net use command list it as existent. But when I try to delete, it says it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell 5 (Windows 10) and above, you can use:

```
Remove-SmbMapping -LocalPath "Y:"
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/remove-smbmapping?view=win10-ps

Comment: This works but for some reason, it still shows up as disconnected in Windows Explorer. Doesn't go away until you restart Windows Explorer. Using `net delete` removes it properly