# Windows 11 unmap a WebDAV "Network Location" (NOT a "Network Drive")

Tags: windows-11, network-location

I accidentally used the `This PC/Add a network location` function to map a WebDAV server. This creates a mapped *folder* appearing under `This PC` without a drive letter, which is not what I wanted.

The `This PC` context menu contains (among others) the following entries:

- Add a network location
- Add a network drive...
- Disconnect a network drive...

But there is no option to unmap the "network location" folder that got created.  That folder does not show up if I try to "Disconnect a network drive", and none of the context menus for the folder, the `This PC` folder or the `Network` folder seem to provide a way to unmap it.

I cannot risk attempting to delete it, in case that propagates the deletion to the server.

Based on [this post](https://superuser.com/q/598355/12296) I then tried

```
C:\Users\jim>net use
New connections will be remembered.

Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           D:        \\home10\D                Microsoft Windows Network
OK           T:        \\home10\T                Microsoft Windows Network
OK           U:        \\Home10\u                Microsoft Windows Network
                       \\obfuscated.com@SSL\resources
                                                Web Client Network
The command completed successfully.
```

followed by

```
C:\Users\jim>net use \\obfuscated.com@SSL\resources /delete
\\obfuscated.com@SSL\resources was deleted successfully.
```

However, the folder that was created under `This PC` did not go away, and clicking it still opens the remote server.  The `net use` command no longer lists the connection, even though it's still present.

```
C:\Users\jim>net use
New connections will be remembered.

Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           D:        \\home10\D                Microsoft Windows Network
OK           T:        \\home10\T                Microsoft Windows Network
OK           U:        \\Home10\u                Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

After that I restarted Explorer, and when that did nothing I rebooted Windows.  Neither resulted in the folder going away.  It's still there, and still connects to the remote WebDAV server, but the `net use` command claims it's not:

```
C:\Users\jim>net use \\obfuscated.com@SSL\resources /delete
The network connection could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.
```

How can I unmap a "Network location" folder in Windows 11?

Comment: After the last net use attempt,  did you restart the computer?

Comment: Yes. First I restarted Explorer and then rebooted. No change, as noted in the edit to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this seems to be due to a couple of bugs in Windows.

I said in the post that opening the folder still connected to the remote.  That was true after the `net use ... /delete`.  However, after rebooting, any attempt to open the folder resulted in a cryptic error message about DNS being unavailable. DNS is working just fine so Windows is confused.

At that point I was able to delete the folder without too much risk of deleting the actual resource (by pressing `delete`).

Seems like there are 3 bugs here:

- No option exposed in the UI to unmap a "network location"
- Explorer not being aware when a "network location" goes away via `net use`
- An incorrect error message when attempting to reconnect a "network connection" that has gone away.